# How to target all underlined elements in a page

Tags: html, css

I want to style all underlined elements in a page full of WordPress blog posts. When I open the code inspector all of the text that was underlined (using the visual editor) added a span style within the html. Is there a way to target all of these individual spans? I want to change the color/letter-spacing ect. of specific words that are underlined.

I know how to do this myself with the html, but I want my client to be able to just underline words that should be emphasized in the visual editor and have it automatically style for him. I don't want to set it as a different heading style because that selects the whole paragraph in the visual editor instead of individual words. Suggestions? I was able to do this with the bold text using: `strong, b {}` not sure what the underline version is.

EDIT: when I go to view page source it looks like this:

```
<p><strong>Competitor 1&amp;2</strong><br />
<em>(Allow no more than 3:00 transitions between EMOMs)</em><br />
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">For load:</span><br />
Every 1:00 for 10:00<br />
1 Jerk in Split + 1 Split Jerk<br />
<em>(add 10lbs/5lbs each set)</em></p>
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline;">For load:</span><br />
Every 1:00 for 10:00<br />
1 Power Clean + 1 Push Press<br />
<em>(add 10lbs/5lbs each set)</em></p>
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline;">For load:</span><br />
Every 1:00 for 10:00<br />
```

Comment: Can you post some code showing one of the spans that were generated?

Comment: yup- just edited the question

Comment: Cheers, I've answered for you based on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css, target it like so;

```
span[style*='underline'] {
    /* CSS goes here */
}
```

That will search for any `span` elements, that have the string `underline` in their `style` attribute

Comment: Doesn't seem to work 2022?

Comment: There’s no reason it shouldn’t work, this is a basic CSS rule and nothing has been removed from the spec that would change this

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a css class on the element ?

```
<span class="underlined">blablabla</span>
```

css:

```
.underlined{text-decoration: underline;}
```

Or if it is auto-generated you might need to use javascript to fetch all elements with that style.